# Open HTML page using Process.Start() method crashes if user cancels after Security Warning

Tags: c#

I have a button to open an HTML page, when the user clicks the button I get a Security Warning in Chrome, which is expected, my issue is that in this Security Warning the user has two options, Open and Cancel, if the user clicks the Open button the file opens just fine but if the user clicks Cancel my app crashes.

Is there a way to avoid the crash if the user cancels? Or better yet, is there a way to avoid the Security Warning all together?

```
    private void HelpPage()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("G:/SomeFolder/Help/index.html");
    }
```

FYI - This file is in a local server.

EDIT: Added Security Warning message.

> Do you want to open this file?

Comment: Most probably application crash because of exception. Wrap the `Start` function all with `try catch` blocks.

Comment: What does the security warning say?

Comment: Oops, see edited answer, added warning message.

Comment: @AramKocharyan - Wrapping the start function in a try catch did the trick. `try{System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/folder/index.html")}catch{//do nothing}`. Thanks a lot!